# PHP thinking OOP : sending and receiving Message : am I getting it right?

Tags: php, oop, interface, polymorphism

**See Updates in the end :**

The current code-base has 1.4k line of purely procedural code which sends sms (has business logic, db connectivity, and everything in one gigantic `if` conditional nested with countless more `if`s, no functions, full of literals, a genuine DailyWTF? candidate). And I have decided to bite the bullet and rewrite the whole damn thing from scratch.
The thing is, this will be my first OOP experience. I read as much as I can about OOD and good practices and decided to start with something simple. I want to implement send/receive of Messages (primarily text/SMS, but MMS, email are to be incorporated in future). So I wrote following as my first commit

```
interface MessageInterface {
    public function setType($type); public function getType();
    public function setContent($content); public function getContent();
    public function sendMessage(); //add more functionalities later
}
class Message implements MessageInterface {
    private $_type; private $_content;
    public function setType($type) { $this->_type = $type; }
    public function getType() { return $this->_type; }
    public function setContent($content) {
        if ($this->_type = 'text') {
            $this->_content = $content;
            return TRUE; // report success
        } else { return FALSE; } // report failure
    }
    public function getContent() { return $this->_content; }
    public function sendMessage() {
        if ($this->_type == 'text') {
            print "Sending ".$this->getContent()." as ".$this->getType()." message\n";
            //do the actual implementation later
            return TRUE;  // report success
        } else { return FALSE; } // report failure
    }
}
$msg = new Message();
$msg->setType('text');
print $msg->getType() . "\n"; //text
$result = $msg->setContent('Hello World!');
if($result)
    $result2 = $msg->sendMessage(); //Sending Hello World! as text message
if($result2)
    print 'Hurray ! Mission accomplished !!';
```

I don't think I am applying the concept of polymorphism properly. I feel that the `if`s shouldn't be there, right? Perhaps they are necessary for `setContent()` but what about `sendMessage()` ? So I thought I will separate the sending part into its own `class SendMessage implements SendMessageInterface`. which will have its own variables for `$server, $protocol` and methods for sending email/text etc. But while writing that class, I realized those `if`s are creeping again as `if($msg->getType() == 'text')` conditionals. To add to that, I am creating a new class which separates the *action* part of my *object* which is confusing to me (e.g. `class door` should be responsible for implementing `close()` and `open()` methods).

Now either I accept that the `if`s will always be there (which feels like defeating the whole purpose of polymorphism) or I *must be doing something wrong*.
From a user's perspective, I am imagining something like :

```
$msg = new Message();
$msg->setType('email'); //or 'text' or 'mms' etc.
$msg->setContent($content); //e.g. $content=array('subject'=>'foo','body'=>'bar')
$msg->sendMessage();
//if the last line is not possible, then perhaps
//$sender = new SendMessage($msg);
//$sender->send();
```

what am I missing here? is it impossible to achieve `$msg->sendMessage();`? Will/should I need different *Message* classes (`MessageEmail`,`MessageText` etc.) ? Should I separate `SendMessage` (and perhaps have `$msg->sendMessage();` call it?)

//and this is when I haven't even thought about *receiving Message* ! God help me !! :(

---

Update 15th Aug 2011 :
After thinking about all the aspects of current code base I have identified following parts which I will need to implement.

```
a. Message Class(es) (type, content, sender, receiver, DateTime of send/receive etc.)
Responsibilities: 
creating and modifying messages
ascribing consistent and appropriate characteristics of a message
b. Send Class(es) (protocol, header info, server/operator to use)
Responsibilities:
Sending messages
Changing the state of Message (for setting send DateTime of Message)
e. Database Class(es) (id, content, to, from, time etc.)
Responsibilities:
Represent Message for storage.
CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) actions on this representation for DBMS.
e. Interfaces (MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, TIMEOUT etc. )
Responsibilities:
Provide interface for communication between various modules.
```

I believe my primary cause of confusion was mixing interfaces with polymorphism([see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059960/php-thinking-oop-sending-and-receiving-message-am-i-getting-it-right/7060054#7060054)) What is your opinion on it?

---

Update 16th Aug 2011
I have mainly used interfaces in order to impose functionality. Here is the short version of 'interfaces.php' file

```
interface MessageInterface {
    //omitting getters for clarity
    public function setType($type);
    public function setSender(IdentityInterface $sender);
    public function setReceiver(IdentityInterface $receiver);
    public function setSendGateway(GatewayInterface $sendGateway);
}
interface IdentityInterface {
    public function setName($name);
    public function setAddress($address);
}
interface GatewayInterface {
    public function setProtocol($protocol);
    public function send(IdentityInterface $sender, IdentityInterface $receiver, ContentInterface $content);
}
```

class implementations are simple (no fancy stuff, as I am yet to integrate `class GatewaySMPP implements GatewayInterface` into my main `Message` class which looks :

```
class Message implements MessageInterface {
    private $_type; private $_content;
    private $_sender; private $_receiver;
    private $_sendGateway; //private $_receiveGateway; private $_dataStorage;
    public function __construct(
        $type = NULL, $content = NULL,
        IdentityInterface $sender = NULL,
        IdentityInterface $receiver = NULL,
        GatewayInterface $sendGateway = NULL
    ) {
        $this->setType($type); $this->setContent($content);
        ($sender === NULL)
            ? $this->setSender(new Identity())
            : $this->setSender($sender);
        ($receiver === NULL)
            ? $this->setReceiver(new Identity())
            : $this->setReceiver($receiver); //similarly for $setSendGateway etc.
    }
    //setters and getters, omitting for clarity
    public function send(...) { //testing pending
        $this->_sendGateway->send($this->getSender(), $this->getReceiver(), $this->getContent ...)
    }
```

The fun part was to implement GatewaySMPP which involved lot of socket operations and response checking. I just need to write a wrapper `public function send()` around `private function _send{PDU,SM}` methods.

While I was thinking about integrating GatewaySMPP I realized that I will be opening/closing sockets for SMPP connection for each Message send operation. This is fine for exercise/testing, but in practice I think I may need to change my logic so that *existing connection is used.* **Question is how?** Here is current logic in order:

```
class GatewaySMPP {
    private $_socket,$_port,$_host //etc.
    public function __construct($host,$port,$user,$passwd) {
        $this->_socket = FALSE;
        $this->_host = $host; //initialize other private variables
    }
    public function init() {
        if($this->_socket !== FALSE) return FALSE; //socket already in use
        $this->_socket = fsockopen($this->_host, $this->_port ...)
        //prepare bind statement for initiating SMPP connection and fwrite to socket
        $this->_sendPDU(BIND, $data)
    }
    public function send($receiver, $sender, $message, ...) {
        //use private functions which do actual socket operations
        $this->_sendSM($receiver, $sender, $message, ...)
    }
    public function end() {
        if($this->_socket === FALSE) return; //socket already closed
        this->_sendPDU(UNBIND, ''); //omitting response check
        $result = fclose($this->_socket); //omitting response check
    }
```

Q. The problem I am facing is, each object of GatewaySMPP will have its own $_socket, so I thought about making GatewaySMPP singleton (*shudders*) or using some global/state variable to keep track of sockets for reuse. A better idea that comes to my mind is if the consumer of these classes uses following logic. 1. Create and use single `$objGatewaySMPP` for all `$objectMessage[]` 2. `objGatewaySMPP->init();` 3. `foreach($objMessage[] as $msg) $msg->send();` 4. `objGatewaySMPP->end();`. That still leaves the problem of concurrent calls by different users of the class? Suggestions/comments please.

Comment: maybe the thousand line code-base nested with `if`s spooked me off, perhaps its okay to use `if`s?

Comment: for what its worth - I think that a 1.4k line app is a nice size for refactoring as a first OOP project. You're not going to get it 100% right first time, but breaking out the code will be a useful exercise and won't take forever. If I were you I would make email and text classes (that extend your base message class). Good luck - don't try and do it all at once, you will end up refactoring many times. This is learning, it's natural.

Comment: Also - I assume the way that email messages and text messages are send are different? Do they have the same inputs though? (content and a recipient?)

Comment: @kissmyface thanks for the encouragement. Yes, the recipient will be same (but I will need to figure out how to represent recipient so it can be used in both context), the content core will be same ('Hello World') but details might change (header, subject etc.) Perhaps I should implement SMS first and see how it goes, then worry about extending the code to add new features (there will be refactoring, which is acceptable as I will learn more)

Comment: *(tip)* [Convert Procedural Design to Objects](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/convert-procedural-design-to-objects)

Comment: @Gordon : updated with last night's work. If you can, please comment/suggest improvements. Thanks

Comment: @Sudhi I think you should first write each of the services without thinking of generalizing their interfaces. You will see what you can abstract once you have working implementations for each of the message services. If you start with the abstraction, chances are your design decisions will ripple to the message gateways that will make them inflexible.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try something like this. This is a quick attempt, but you should always try to minimise code duplication.

```
<?php

// Message Types

abstract class Message 
{
    private $content; // for email this is the body of the email / for sms it is the 140 characters
    private $sendService;

    public function __construct(SendService $sendService){
        $this->sendService = $sendService;
    }

    public function send($recipient)
    {
        $this->sendService->send($recipient, $this);
    }

}

class EmailMessage extends Message
{
    private $subject;
    private $header;
    //setters and getters / maybe a constructor
}

class SMSMessage extends Message
{
    private $from;
    //setters and getters / maybe a constructor
}


//Services for sending messages

interface SendService
{
    function send(Recipient $recipient, $message);
}

class EmailSendService implements SendService
{
    function send($recipient, EmailMessage $message){
        // you can use only the attributes from the recipient that you need (email address)
        // you can be sure that the message has a header and a subject because you are enforcing
        // the type allowed to be passed to this function
        // do email sending stuff
    }           
}

class SMSSendService implements SendService
{
    function send($recipient, SMSMessage $message){
        // you can use only the attributes from the recipient that you need (tel number)
        // do sms sending stuff
    }           
}

// Defines a 'user' that can be used for both messge types
class Recipient
{
    private $email;
    private $tel;
    private $name;
    //setters and getters
}


// how you would use the above

// 1 - set up recipient - in the real world you would probably have something that would provide this
// to you, like a database lookup
$recipient = new Recipient();
$recipient->setEmail('abc@def.com');
$recipient->setName('Herp Derp');
$recipient->setTel('07770000000000');

// 2 - get a service for sending your message 
$sendService = new SMSSendService();

// 3 - create your message by passing it a service which it can use to send itself
$message = new SMSMessage($sendService);

// 4 - set attributes of your message and then send (passing a recipient to send to)
$message->setContent('lorem ipsum herp derp doop');
$message->send($recipient);
```

Comment: upvoted , thanks this cleared up lot of my confusion, I am modifying my code and incorporating yours and few other suggestions from this thread. Will update my question when I am done.

Comment: @Sudhi I like this one, so I wont add another answer as request via Twitter, ok?

Comment: @Gordon : thanks, nevertheless I will keep updating this question with my progress, and thanks for the tip :) What is your take on [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059960/php-thinking-oop-sending-and-receiving-message-am-i-getting-it-right/7060054#7060054) ?

Comment: @Sudhi seems okay to me, too. In both cases, I could also imagine not to have different Message types but rather just different Message Gateways. A basic message is identical for SMS, MMS and eMail. You got recipient, sender and message. What differs is how they are delivered. It really depends on the amount of features and the amount of control you need. Try simple first and then gradually refactor until it meets all the requirements.

Comment: exactly my point @Gordon : IMO the delivery of message which is an _action_ on _message_ must be a method of `Message` class. However, the complexity lies in the fact that this _action_ expects different data attributes from `Message` class. As for features/controls, this is an exercise, so perhaps I should focus on getting the SMS part done and worry about other things later. In fact I should completely remove the email feature and let other class/code manage it. I maybe falling into the trap of overengineering.

Answer (score 1):

With interfaces you can do it without extending other class. And it's great.

I'll try say in code (because my English is worse than my PHP)

```
<?php
Interface IMessage
{
    public function Send();
}

class EMail implements IMessage
{
    private $content;
    private $to;
    private $subject;

    public function __construct($to, $subject, $content)
    {
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function Send()
    {
        mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->content);
    }
}

class SMS implements IMessage
{
    private $num;
    private $from;
    private $message;

    public function __construct($num, $message, $from = '')
    {
        $this->num = $num;
        $message = substr(trim($message), 0, 140);
        $from = empty($from) ? $num : $from;
    }

    public function Send()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: errm, correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that _interface_ enforce _polymorphism_ on all classes which implement the said _interface_ ? (assuming each class will have different logic of executing the interface)

Comment: no no ! your code is fine, and I can understand it, its the concept of interface and polymorphism that I am confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the method `setContent` will only be used for text types (well I assume this because you're doing the conditional check), it seems logical to break down the class in some way, perhaps into a baseclass `Message` and children ala `SMSMessage` and `MMSMessage`. In the `SMSMessage` you can define `SetContent()` and then perhaps `AttachImage()` for for example the `MMSMessage`. Another approach is defining `SetContent()` as abstract in the baseclass Message and then force the inheritors to define that method - that is if you are planning to do some logic in that method.

On a side note procedural code is not necessarily bad perse, but in your case it does sound severe. If it's worth refactoring all that is another story though.

Comment: hmm, good point, thanks, perhaps you are right and I need to segregate my base class (Message) and extend it to particular one (SMSMessage, MMSMessage etc.) As for refactoring its more of a personal agenda to prove OOP (the current code works just fine) and change the way "we" work (how can I tell others in my team to use OOP if I don't get it in the first place?)

Answer (score -4):

Move to another language. (not kidding). PHP's OOP support is quite lacking and I would hate to try to program in it for anything other then close-to-web related tasks.